# SWI-Prolog: how to load rdf triples using semweb/rdf_db library?

Tags: rdf, swi-prolog

I have a rdf file (file.trp) in n-triples format, where each line is a well-formed triple:

"subject predicate object ."

I tried to use rdf_load in semweb/rdf_db to load it into memory, but failed. Here is what I tried:

```
?- rdf_load('file.trp').

?- rdf_load('file.trp', [format(triples)]).
```

The trace shows that the goal fails at:

```
rdf_db:rdf_load_stream/3
```

which calls

```
rdf_load_db_/3
```

which is probably defined in a foreign library.

the manual says it supports xml and triples. But it only loads rdf xml files. How can I load such rdf triple file?

Thanks,
Li

Answer (score 2):

The library(semweb/rdf_db) can be extended with several plugins to support additional
inputs (URLs, compressed, different triple formats).  Notably:

- Loading library(semweb/rdf_turtle) makes it read .ttl (Turtle)
- Loading library(semweb/rdf_zlib_plugin) makes it process .gz files (compressed)
- Loading library(semweb/rdf_http_plugin) makes it load from http:// URLs
- Loading library(semweb/rdf_ntriples) makes it load the ntriples format
  (this is only provided with the latest development version; 6.3.8).

Answer (score 1):

The ***[manual](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=rdf_load/2)*** suggests that the predicate `rdf_load/2` supports either the [RDF/XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-rdf-syntax/) or, it's 'internal quick load and cache format', which is probably not the n-triples format.

Firstly, you'll need to import the following to make use of this predicate anyhow:

```
:- use_module(library(semweb/rdf_db)).
```

Secondly, I think you'll need to convert your triples into an appropriate format which is readable by this predicate, such as [RDF/XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-rdf-syntax/), and use the call like this:

```
 rdf_load('file.xml', [format(xml)]).
```

You can use this [online converter](http://www.mindswap.org/2002/rdfconvert/) for converting between n-triples and RDF/XML format (amongst others).